# How to set struts fields dynamically in jsp pages

Tags: java, struts

I have a jsp page where i have to show some values using struts framework.i.e

```
<logic:iterate id="DetailsFormBean" name="DetailsFormBean"  property="listOfUser"> 

<td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="start_day"/></td>
<td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="start_time"/></td>
<td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="end_time"/></td>
<td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="a_imei"/></td>
```

so these field are populating using formbeans(property) of struts.

Now i have a requirement that all these fields may not come together all the time i.e if i want to show `start_day` & `start_time` the other fields should not come. How can i set fields dynamically in jsp pages ?? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `<c:if>`  or if tag of **JSTL** core tag library in JSP is one of the most versatile and useful tag. JSTL if tag allows you to test for a condition, like checking for a particular parameter in `requestScope`, `sessionScope` or `pageScope`.

```
<c:if test="${Your Condintion}">
   <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="start_day"/></td>
   <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="start_time"/></td>
</c:if>
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/5-jstl-core-if-tag-examples-in-jsp.html#ixzz2b4JoU8LF

Answer (score -1):

It is depending upon your business requirement how you display the time and date fields. Based on that, you can change the value for example:

```
<%
if ("your_business_requirement" == 'dateandtime')
{
%>
 <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="start_time"/></td>
 <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="end_time"/></td>
<%
}
else
{
%>
 <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="end_time"/></td>
 <td align="left" ><bean:write name="DetailsFormBean" property="a_imei"/></td> 
<%
 } %>
```